# Ajuda com jogo de War em Java

Tags: java

estou tentando fazer um jogo de war em java onde o mapa do jogo é um simples vetor de 1 a 16 cada número sendo um país, fiz um Random para sortear ao jogador o país que ele irá iniciar, mas como atribui-lo ao Jogador sem que eu tenha que fazer 16 if's?

```
   public class Mundo {



    int sensalia = 1;
    int kemia = 2;
    int sema = 3;
    int kardia = 4;
    int torkuha = 5;
    int ohistet = 6;
    int baselia = 7;
    int dottinia = 8;
    int zellzach = 9;
    int freusen = 10;
    int sinusia = 11;
    int kuclasia = 12;
    int phlius = 13;
    int plasisia = 14;
    int dorumia = 15;
    int cresonia = 16;


    public int nacaoMae(){
     Random rand = new Random(16 + 1);

     int result = rand.nextInt();


  }
}
```

Comment: Por que ao invés de criar uma variável pra um país, você não cria um vetor de strings e atribui o índice do vetor?

Comment: Qual é o limite de jogadores? Qual limite pra cada país?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque todos os Países em um vetor de String, após gerar um numero aleatório, você pega o índice do vetor como se fosse o numero que setou para cada País..

Por exemplo:

seu result deu 3;
então:
[image: EXEMPLO]

O país atribuido para o jogador seria KARDIA.

```
jogador = vetor[result];
```